# Sample code for insert and delete row iphone

Tags: iphone

Is there any sample code provides apple for insert and delete rows in a UITableView iphone ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the comprehensive article in the iOS Developer library about [Inserting and Deleting Rows and Sections](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html).

Comment: "willcodejavaforfood 6,666" <-- a SO reputation of 6,666! Where's my holy water?

Comment: Well it's gone now so you are safe :)